# How to execute def command without showing None

Tags: python, function, nonetype

I'm trying to make a function run another function and then ask for input.
The thing is that when I use the print option it returns `None` after exectuing the def, but when I use the return option it just prints the print_board(board) and finishes the function, meaning, without asking for the inputs.

How can I execute a command without showing `None` and without finishing the function?

```
def main():
     print print_board(board)
     x = int(raw_input("Enter row "))
     y = int(raw_input("Enter column "))
     z = int(raw_input("Enter digit "))
     return is_valid_move(x,y,z)
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
def main():
     print_board(board)
     ...
```

This will call `print_board()`, but will neither print out its return value (`None`) nor terminate `main()`.